# Using enum with a switch case String for my assignment

Tags: java, string, enums, switch-statement

I've made changes to the code and was able to successfully I hope use the switch case with a String. Now I just need help declaring two variables for the string getDirection. I need it to be declared as "Right" and "Left"

```
String quit= "exit";
  String choice;
  String getDirection= "Right";//I need it to be declared as both left and right
  
  quit.equalsIgnoreCase("exit");
  
do
{
  System.out.println("would you like the bug to move or turn around?");
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Or enter 'exit' to quit");
  choice= scan.nextLine();
  
  option options=option.MOVE;
  
  switch(options)
  {
      case MOVE:
          b.move();
          if (getDirection.equals("Right"))
              System.out.println("The bug moved 1 unit towards " + b.getDirection("Right ") + " and is now at position " + b.getPosition());
              else if (getDirection.equals("Left"))
              System.out.println("The bug moved 1 unit towards " + b.getDirection("Left ") + " and is now at position " + b.getPosition());
```

Comment: It is standard practice to name enum values uppercase, as `MOVE`, `TURN`.

Comment: And, generally best to name an enum class in singular rather than plural.

Comment: Thank you, I have made the corrections @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: This can never be true: `if (d.equals("Right") & d.equals("Left"))`

Comment: The string argument here has no use: `public String getDirection(String dir)//gives the direction the bug is faced`

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (b.getDirection.equals("Right"))//this getDirection is showing up as an error
```

That's because there's no member variable called getDirection in class Bug.

You have defined a local variable called getDirection, which is unrelated to class Bug.

Probably you intended a method call, b.getDirection(), by analogy with your similar calls in the same section of code.

Incidentally, IMO variables should have noun phrases for names, not verb phrases.  So, method getDirection() is well-named, variable getDirection is not.

Comment: I'm still getting an error message using method b.getDirection().equals("Right")

Comment: What is the exact error?  And please post the source for the class Bug. Otherwise we can only guess what it looks like.

Comment: I have added the Bug class and believe I have successfully used the case switch, however now I need help declaring two variables for the String getDirection. I need it to be both "Left" and "Right". Also right now I have the output dashes (-) going vertically, is there a way for me to get them to show up horizontally with the (X)?

Comment: I don't know what the comment in `String getDirection= "Right";//I need it to be declared as both left and right` could mean.  The use of this variable decides which way the bug moves. It cannot move left and right at the same time.   It seems odd you've hardwired this choice into the program, but I assumed that was just "program still being developed". Nevertheless, for any single MOVE, it's got to be left **or** right, not both.

Comment: how do I declare it so it moves right or left? because right now its only moving right

Comment: How should it decide whether to move right or left?  I don't know, it's not my program.  User input?  Random choice?  First one then the other?